# Show all possible error-messages for fields (Django)

Tags: django

In Django, say I have a User field and I want to change the "this user alread exist" error message. I know I can parse a dictionary in e.g `forms.py` like

```
class MyForm(Form):
.
.
.
  error_messages={"unique": ("Wups, enter a unique username")}
```

but it requires I know the key/value pair, which might not always be obvious what the key is.

Is there a way (in the Django documentation it seems pretty scattered) where these error-message key/value pairs are, or what is the most easy way to find those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the common ones are as

```
'null': 'This field cannot be null.'
'blank': 'This field cannot be blank.'
'invalid' : 'Enter a valid email address.'
'invalid_choice': 'Value is not a valid choice.'
'required': 'This field is required.'
'max_length': '...'
'min_length': '...'
'max_value': '...'
'min_value': '...'
'max_digits': '...'
'invalid_list': '...'
'max_decimal_places': '....'
'empty': '....'
...
```

and with any other error message you face and don't know the type you can simply do a `form.errors.as_json()` it will return you the errors as

```
{
    "sender": [{"message": "Enter a valid email address.", "code": "invalid"}],
    "subject": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}],
}
```

then that you could use the code as `key` and the write your message for it.

Answer (score 0):

All messages in Django - including the error messages you want to change - are translated, and stored in translation files (*.po extension). You can override only these files, and Django will then use your version for whichever languages you support.

Read more on translations in general for Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/

Read on creating translation files:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files

To dump all translations, it might work to add the `JavaScriptCatalog` or the `JsonCatalog` that come with Django to your `urls.py` as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.views.i18n
This will include all translations for all apps listed in INSTALLED_APPS unless you restrict it.

Comment: Although this is a valid answer, it won't satisfy the case when you want to change the message only for a single field or a single form class.

Comment: @GwynBleidD - the question is about generic error messages like the validation of "unique" which are all managed via the gettext pipeline (`makemessages/compilemessages`) in Django.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the error messages for particular field types [on this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#built-in-field-classes) of the Django documentation. For each field type there is an `Error message keys` specified.

You can also look for the code of the field you want to use and there should be a `default_error_messages` specified either directly or in its ancestors. Look through all of them for all the error messages you can overwrite.